# $\Bbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $B(x,r):=\{y\in\Bbb{R}:d(x,y)<r\}$ for any $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and for any $r\in\Bbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

> **Statement**
>
> $\Bbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $B(x,r):=\{y\in\Bbb{R}:d(x,y)<r\}$ for any $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and for any $r\in\Bbb{R}$
>
> *Proof*. So we define a function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\rightarrow B(x,r)$ through the condiction 
>   $$
> f(y_1,...,y_n)=(x_1+\frac{y_1}{1+\frac{1}r\sqrt{y_1^2+...+y_n^2}},...,x_n+\frac{y_n}{1+\frac{1}r\sqrt{y_1^2+...+y_n^2}}) 
> $$
>   where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the coordinates of $x$ and $y$ for any $i=1,...,n$; and then we prove that $f$ is an homeomorphism. So if $y,z\in\Bbb{R}^n$ are such that $f(y)=f(z)$ then it follows that
>   $$
> \frac{y_i}{1+\frac{1}r\sqrt{y_1^2+...+y_n^2}}=\frac{z_i}{1+\frac{1}r\sqrt{z_1^2+...+z_n^2}}
> $$
>   for any $i=1,...,n$ and so
>   $$
> \frac{\sqrt{y_1^2+...+y_n^2}}{1+\frac{1}r\sqrt{y_1^2+...+y_n^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{z_1^2+...+z_n^2}}{1+\frac{1}r\sqrt{z_1^2+...+z_n^2}}
> $$
>   and so
>   $$
> \sqrt{y_1^2+...+y_n^2}=\sqrt{z_1^2+...+z_n^2}
> $$
>   and so
>   $$
> \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}r\sqrt{y_1^2+...+y_n^2}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}r\sqrt{z_1^2+...+z_n^2}}
> $$
>   and so
>   $$
> y_i=z_i
> $$
>   for any $i=1,..,n$ and so we can conclude that $x=y$.

Unfortunately I can't prove that $f$ is surjective and I can't calculate $f^{-1}$ and so to prove that it is continuous. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: You should try the simplest case first: r=1 and n=1. From there, you can try to find a formula for arbitrary r and n=1, and then generalize to any r and n

Comment: It is enough to consider the standard open unit ball $B(\mathbf{0};1)$. Then, by simple algebraic manipulation,  you realize that $g(z)=\frac{z}{1-|z|}$ is the inverse function of $f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the homeomorphism $f(x)=\frac{x}{\|x\|+1}$, of $\Bbb R^n$ with $B(\vec{0},1)$, so we multiply the vector $x$ by the scalar $\frac{1}{\|x\|+1}$; the result has norm

$$\left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|+1}\right\| = \frac{\|x\|}{\|x\|+1}< 1$$ so $f(x) \in B(\vec{0},1)$ as required. The $+1$ below in the fraction also ensures that we never divide by $0$ for the scalar. $f$ is continuous as $x \to \|x\|$ is, addition is too, and scalar multiplication as well, and it's a composition of those.

To see what the inverse is we take $y \in B(\vec{0},1)$ and try to find a pre-image under $f$, so an $x$ such that $\frac{x}{\|x\|+1} = y$. We get that $\|x\|y + y = x$ and so, as clearly $x=ty$ for some $t>0$, we see that $ty = (t\|y\|+1)y$ which tells us that we must have $t=t\|y\|+1$, or $t = \frac{1}{1-\|y\|}$, well defined as $\|y\| < 1$ and we have found the inverse $g(y) = \frac{y}{1-\|y\|}$ from $B(\vec{0},1)$ back to $\Bbb R^n$.

Finally note that $B(x,r)$ is homeomorphic to $B(\vec{0},1)$ via $h(y)= x+ry$ (first scale $y$ then translate) from $B(\vec{0},1)$ to $B(x,r)$. So all open balls are homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Okay, thanks too much!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is a rather classical result that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ diffeomorphic to the open unit ball $\mathbb{B}_n:=B(\mathbf{0},1)$. The functions
$F:\mathbb{B}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, $G:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{B}_n$ given by

$$ F(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-|x|^2}}$$
 $$ G(y) = \frac{y}{\sqrt{1+|y|^2}}$$
provide such deffeomorphism for $G=F^{-1}$, and is is easy to see that both $F\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{B}_n)$ and $G\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (chain rule).

Comment: Sorry, could you prove that $F$ is an homeomorphism such that $G=F^{-1}$?

Comment: That $F=G^{-1}$ is easy, but you should do it. Substite $F(x)$ on G and you will get $x$. The next part is also easy. F (similarly $G$) is the composition of differentiable functions (hence continuous and all that Jazz)

Comment: Sorry, I try to do it but unfortunately I was not be able. So could you do it?

Comment: which part? The differentiability part should be easy. $f$ is the product the identity map $x\mapsto x$, and the scalar function $x\mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-|x|^2}}$. The later is ba only when |x|=1$, but those points are not part of the open unit ball.

Comment: That $G=F^{-1}$ requires some algebraic manipulation: $G(F(x))=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-|x|^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{|x|^2}{1-|x|^2}}}$